# php's strip_tags() won't work

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to tweak a tiny bit a wordpress, but i am level 0 in php, so i kinda suck :/

I want to add a custom 'tweet this' button (i know there already is a gazillion of them, i just wanted to do it on my own, for fun)

So, i'm trying this :

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=<?php strip_tags(the_excerpt()) ?>" >tweet this</a>
```

the_excerpt() returns `"<p> ... excerpt ... </p>"` and the strip_tags function does not strip those `<p>` tags !

What do i do wrong ?

Thanks, and sorry if it is obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that `the_excerpt()` does not return its contents to `strip_tags()`, but outputs it directly using `echo`. So `strip_tags()` (which would need a preceding `echo` by the way to do any work) can't do anything.

Use [get_the_excerpt()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt) instead (line break inserted for clarity, remove when using):

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=
<?php echo strip_tags(get_the_excerpt()); ?>" >tweet this</a>
```

By the way, I would also `urlencode()` the excerpt, you're bound to run into trouble otherwise if it contains `"`double quotes or other funny characters.

Comment: Ah yes, that wasn't immediately clear from the question.  However, given the nightmare that is Wordpress's global scoping and function naming scheme, it becomes obvious in retrospect. :D +1

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look right by common sense: `<?php strip_tags(the_excerpt()) ?>`, then the WP doc explained, [the_excerpt's API doc](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_excerpt), it said it echoes instead of returning it.
Well, use `ob_start` to workaround.

```
ob_start("callback");
the_excerpt();
$excerpt = ob_get_contents();

?>
<a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=<?php echo strip_tags($excerpt) ?>" >tweet this</a>
<?php
```

Note: I don't have any WordPress API experience.